# How do I return JSON structured as the transpose of json_agg() in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, json

I'm trying to convert an arbitrary subquery to JSON in PostgreSQL.

`json_agg()` seems like the obvious tool for the job. For example:

```
select json_agg(a) from (
    select count(lead_source), lead_source from leads_table group by lead_source order by count desc
) as a;
```

However, data is structured as `the_data[row_number]["column_name"]`. 
Suppose I want data structured as `the_data["column_name"][row_number]`. That is, I want the transpose structure of json_agg(). How do I do that?

My best effort is:

```
select row_to_json(row(array_to_json(array_agg(count)), array_to_json(array_agg(lead_source)))) from (
    select count(lead_source), lead_source from leads_table group by lead_source order by count desc
) as a;
```

But this has (at least) two drawbacks:

1. It doesn't work for an arbitrary subquery. The column names must be hardcoded each time `array_agg()` is used.
2. The column names become `f1`, `f2`, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will take care of the f1,f2,f3 name issue, but unfortunately can't think of an easy way for an arbitrary query.

```
 SELECT row_to_json(r) from 
      (SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(count)) As count, 
              array_to_json(array_agg(lead_source)) As lead_source
      FROM (
        SELECT count(lead_source), lead_source from leads_table group by lead_source    
          ORDER BY count desc
    ) as a) AS r;
```

This one is not quite as short but will allow you to to put an arbitrary in your a subquery and output the columns. (so solving both issue 1 and issue 2).  It piggy backs on hstore so if you don't have hstore installed, you'll need to do a:
    CREATE EXTENSION hstore;

```
SELECT  ('{' || string_agg(sv, ',') || '}')::json
 FROM (SELECT ('"' || (kv).key || '"' || ':' 
   || array_to_json(array_agg((kv).value) ) )   As sv
FROM (SELECT each(hstore(a)) As kv from 
  (
   SELECT count(lead_source), lead_source from leads_table group by lead_source    
      ORDER BY count desc
   ) as a) As r
 GROUP By (kv).key) As r2;
```